# Buffered Input Stream showing previous data

Tags: java, sockets, networking

1.Connected 2 clients using sockets

2.Client1 writes something to socket

3.Client 2 reads data

4.Client 2 then writes data to the same socket

5.Client 1 now reads data

the problem is occuring at step 5 .
data available in buffered input stream in step 5 to client1 also contains some amount of data written at step2.i.e. the input stream  is not cleared when in step 3 client 2 reads data.
Please help

Comment: It is highly unlikely that there is a bug in the buffered input stream in Java, so make sure you are reading all data that is supposed to be read.

Comment: Your question is confusing, the biggest issue being that these are two completely different BufferedInputStreams. As an aside, are you flushing the Streams after reading in data? Can you show some code and greatly clarify your problem?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you have one socket per client and a separate stream for sending and receiving. As such its not possible to confuse data between clients or data going in or out.

I suggest you have a reading and writing thread on the client and a thread on the server.

Answer (score 0):

you mustn't be flushing the stream.Try appending "\n" at the end of your strings.

**PS**:IMHO using [scanner](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) instead of buffered stream will be easier.

Happy coding.